# creating ruby method that executes javascript and passes it arguments

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with capybara and cucumber to test an application written in ruby on rails. I need to create a ruby method that takes three arguments and passes the arguments within the execute_script() function. The code is below.

```
def shadow_click(elm1, elm2, index )
  execute_script('
    alert(elm1);
    alert(elm2);
    alert(index);
  ')
end
```

How can I pass the arguments into the javascript code?
I tried the ruby standard #{elm1} and that didn't work.

Comment: Did you try: `execute_script("alert(#{elm1});")`?

Comment: yes we tried that code

Comment: Did you try what I posted? Pardon me if you already have. I am asking because I see you have used `'`(single quote) while Ruby string interpolation works with `"`(double quote).

Comment: Ruby string interpolation works, I just used it in my app. What about `execute_script("alert("#{escape_javascript(elm1)}");")`? (extra quotes for the `alert` and `escape_javascript`)